# Не перегружена ли разметка?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, бэм

Друзья, всем привет! После того как изучил БЭМ, верстаю только с ним. Но порой мне кажется, что моя разметка слишком перегружена длинными названиями классов, и читать её затруднительно. Нужен взгляд со стороны:)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, норм или я не так понял БЭМ?

```
<section class="our-blog">
    <div class="our-blog__container">

        <div class="our-blog__title">
            <h3 class="our-blog__header">Our Blog</h3>
            <h4 class="our-blog__sub-header">Check our latest news</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="our-blog__posts">
            <article class="our-blog__post post">
                <div class="post__image">
                    <img src="pics/blog/1.jpg" alt="blog post picture">
                </div>
                <div class="post__info">
                    <div class="post__title">
                        <h3>all about headshots inside professional studios</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post__sub-info post__sub-info--one-row">
                        <div class="post__comments">
                            <img src="pics/icons/common/comments.png" alt="comments">
                            <span class="post__comments-count">15 Comments</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post__date">
                            <span>June, 2021</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>

        <div class="our-blog__see-all-posts">
            <button class="our-blog__see-all-button">See All Posts</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Вопрос довольно общий и на него нельзя дать правильного ответа. Скорее всего его закроют. Но могу дать моментов, которые я бы выделил. `our-blog` и `our-blog__container` по сути одно и то же, я бы их объединил под именем `our-blog` и избавился от лишнего `div`. Второе, это `post__title` я бы применил сразу к тегу `h3`. Третье, из блока `post__date` удалил бы `span`, ибо он не несет никакой нагрузки. В остальном, более-менее читабельный код. По поводу длинных названий - тут они не особо длинные, а при деплое они будут обфусцированы и минифицированы и в продакшен коде займут несколько символов.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста)
Ну закроют значит закорют, что уж тут поделаешь...
Мне кажется, что можно дать ответ, почему бы и нет

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Для код-ревью у stckovrflow есть специальный сайт [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Можно туда обращаться, если есть необходимость

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про этот ресурс.
По поводу лишних тегов в разметке - абсолютно с Вами согласен, верстка давняя, так что..)
Но вот хотел бы узнать Ваше мнение: ведь теги в разметку могут добавляться также для определенного "наслаивания" стилей. Можно ли судить о нужности или ненужности тега, не взглянув на стили?

Comment: Если можно одним стилем изменить поведение, вместо "наслаивания" стилей (комбинация селекторов), то проще заменить, так как в данном случае получается обертка над оберткой, хотя можно их объединить. В целом, я бы придерживался такого правила, если можно сократить вложенность - лучше ее сократить.